# C++ not declared in Scope error

Tags: c++, header, scope

Hi I'm teaching myself C++ and I'm getting this error

```
'verifyDateInput' was not declared in this scope
```

The error occurs on the call to verifyDateInput below.

```
    void setAll(std::string dateString) {

        if(verifyDateInput(dateString.c_str())) {

            std::vector<std::string> results = split(dateString, '/');
            month = results.at(0).;
            day = results.at(1);
            year = results.at(2);
        }
    }
```

I'm sure this is just some nuance of the language that I'm not getting. The function call is within a struct declaration in a header file, and within the header file I have the declaration of the function. (not sure if declaration is the right word.....the thing where I just write the function signature)

```
bool verifyDateInput(const char* input);
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Is the function declaration *before* the call in the code?

Comment: Have you declared `verifyDateInput` above or below `setAll` in the header file? It should be above.

Comment: Show us the declaration of `verifyDateInput`, seems from your question that its a member function of that mysterious struct...

Comment: WOW I knew it was something tiny like that....no the function declaration is after the struct....*head smack* thanks! I'll make an official answer. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So remember kids, always declare your functions above their usages in a program file. The problem was that my function declaration is below the struct declaration.

Thanks to Naveen and chris for immediately recognizing this

Answer (score 1):

> The function call is within a struct declaration in a header file

You mean you wrote the declaration inside the structure definition like this?

```
struct SomeStruct
{
    // variables
    bool verifyDateInput(const char* input);
};
```

In this case `verifyDateInput` is a member function of `SomeStruct`. You will need to define the function somewhere like:

```
bool SomeStruct::verifyDateInput( const char* input );
{
    // code
}
```

and also call it using an object of `SomeStruct` like

```
SomeStruct somObj;
somObj.verifyDateInput( strVal );
```

If you didn't mean a member function, try writing it outside the structure definition.

Comment: No I mean the call to the function is within the struct. The declaration was after the struct declaration